# iMAcros EVAL to replace new lines in text

Tags: firefox, eval, imacros

I have this code.

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/\s\s/gi,' ').replace(/\n/gi,' ').replace(/\s\s/gi,' ');" )
```

I am using it to replace new lines and multiple characters in text and new lines. I want the scraped text from page to be in one line no matter the size of text. The code above gives error.

```
wrong format of SET command, line 21 (Error code: -910)
```

How to debug this code and get this EVAL working?

Answer (score 2):

Your `EVAL` works in this way:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/\s\s/gi,' ').replace(/\\n/gi,' ').replace(/\s\s/gi,' ');")
```

and this does as well:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/\s/g, ' ');")
```

Comment: Will try...    I used few lines and got undefined. Now I will try this code you made.